# Callable signature not found in promise (Flow, React Native, JS)

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

My app shows a list of question that are displayed on the first screen upon loading.

I'm currently trying to implement it so that it listens to AppState and upon it becoming 'active' again, it will refresh the list of questions again to make sure the list is up to date.

I'm currently using MobX to keep track of my state.

Everything appears to be working fine, but flow is generating the following errors...

```
Library type error:
/private/tmp/flow/flowlib_1950abc4/core.js:666
666:       onFulfill?: (value: R) => Promise<U> | U,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. Callable signature not found in
 17:             .then(this.refreshQuestions()) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Promise. See: packages/mobile/src/questionList/QuestionRepository.js:17

packages/mobile/src/questionList/QuestionRepository.js:16
             v----------------------------
 16:         this.loadQuestionsFromCache()
 17:             .then(this.refreshQuestions()) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
                 -----------------------------^ call of method `then`
666:       onFulfill?: (value: R) => Promise<U> | U,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. Callable signature not found in. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_1950abc4/core.js:666
 17:             .then(this.refreshQuestions()) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Promise
```

This is my constructor and the relevant methods that are being called...

```
    constructor() {
        this.loadQuestionsFromCache()
            .then(this.refreshQuestions()) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
            .then(this.startListeningForStateChanges()) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
            .catch(() => {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Ooops!',
                    'Something went wrong when I tried to load everyones questions :( please try refreshing me',
                    [{text: 'OK'}],
                    {cancelable: false}
                )
            })
    }

    @action('List is refreshing (true/false) updated')
    updateIsListRefreshing(isRefreshing: boolean) {
        this.isListRefreshing = isRefreshing
    }

    @action('Set question list')
    setQuestions(questions: Question) {
        this.questions = questions
    }

    handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: string) => {
        if (nextAppState === 'active') {
            this.refreshQuestions()
        }
    }

    startListeningForStateChanges() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line complexity, max-statements
    async refreshQuestions() {
        if (this.isListRefreshing) {
            return
        }

        try {
            this.updateIsListRefreshing(true)

            const response = await fetch(serverURL)

            if (response.status === 200) {
                const questionsText = await response.text()

                this.setQuestions(JSON.parse(questionsText).map(Question.of))
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('questions', questionsText)
            }

            this.updateIsListRefreshing(false)
        } catch (error) {
            this.updateIsListRefreshing(false)
        }
    }

    async loadQuestionsFromCache() {
        const questionsText = await AsyncStorage.getItem('questions')

        if (questionsText) {
            this.setQuestions(JSON.parse(questionsText).map(Question.of))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
constructor() {
    this.loadQuestionsFromCache()
        .then(this.refreshQuestions) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
        .then(this.startListeningForStateChanges) // eslint-disable-line promise/prefer-await-to-then
        .catch(() => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Ooops!',
                'Something went wrong when I tried to load everyones questions :( please try refreshing me',
                [{text: 'OK'}],
                {cancelable: false}
            )
        })
}

@action.bound
updateIsListRefreshing(isRefreshing: boolean) {
    this.isListRefreshing = isRefreshing
}

@action('Set question list')
setQuestions(questions: Question) {
    this.questions = questions
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: string) => {
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
        this.refreshQuestions()
    }
}

@action.bound
startListeningForStateChanges() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
}

@action.bound
async refreshQuestions() {
    if (this.isListRefreshing) {
        return
    }

    try {
        this.updateIsListRefreshing(true)

        const response = await fetch(serverURL)

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const questionsText = await response.text()

            this.setQuestions(JSON.parse(questionsText).map(Question.of))
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('questions', questionsText)
        }

        this.updateIsListRefreshing(false)
    } catch (error) {
        this.updateIsListRefreshing(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain further?